# Index of list elements for user data

Tags: database, list, unity-game-engine, arraylist, user-controls

Ive a specific question:

In my game differend users can add an account to a local based app. Basically i thougth about saving names, scores and choosed avatar images to three differend lists. But i relized following:

When adding a value (f.e. "0") to a list called userScore, unity debugs same values at the same index, but the count value is correct. Lets say i add five times "0" to my userScore list, the userScore.Count = 5, but when iam using following debug code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < userScore.Count; i++)
         {
             Debug.Log("Score " + userScore[i] + "with Index " + userScore.IndexOf(userScore[i]) );
     }
```

i get the result 0 with index 0 (five times) - but it should be

0 with index 0 
0 with index 1 
0 with index 2 
0 with index 3 
0 with index 4

Can someone explain me why? And has someone a better idea to make player stats with specific values? Users can be added and deleted, so i would have to have a dynamic system where i can get the player name, score and choosed avatar. In my opinion i would achieve this with those lists, but probably there is a better way.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why making things complicated?

```
for (int i = 0; i < userScore.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Score " + userScore[i] + "with Index " + i );
}
```

As indicated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) `IndexOf` returns the index of the **first occurrence** of a value in the List. If you have a list containing `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, calling `IndexOf(1)` will return 0, because 1 is found at index 0, no matter how many times you call `IndexOf`

---

I advise you to use a struct / class in order to contain the data of your users since you plan to manipulate more information:

```
public struct UserData
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Score;
    public int AvatarIndex;
}

// ...

public List<UserData> UserData;

for (int i = 0; i < UserData.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("Score " + UserData.Score[i] + "with Index " + i );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just relized you answered in the unity forum too. :) Ive a question to your struct UserData - how would i add users and delete them? How will they be safed durring several sessions?

Comment: Adding users and deleting them is done by adding / removing an element from the list.

Comment: If you want to persistenly save the users, there are several possibilities, you will find plenty of resources on this subject. A very simple solution (supposing the struct does not contain Unity objects such as GameObject / Sprite / ...) would be to use `JsonUtility.ToJson` + [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext) in order to save and [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) + `JsonUtility.FromJson` in order to load.